# How to call a Class method dynamically in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have the model name saved in a variable:

```
"#{class_name.singularize}"
```

from another controller I want to see the columns defined for this model. I tried

```
send("#{class_name.singularize}.columns")
```

but its trying to call `Page.columns` as a method of the class I am currently working in rather than the `Page` class. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize):

```
class_name.singularize.constantize.columns
```

Comment: undefined method `constanstize' for "Page":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: @j_mcnally Because I can't type, it's `constantize`. Updated answer.

Comment: awsome! thanks so much i had no idea this could be done, you ROCK!

Comment: Perhaps slightly irrelevant, but it might be interesting to know that `constantize` is a rails construct. The equivalent ruby expression would be `Object.const_get('SomeString')`

Comment: Yes i saw this when i was looking at the constantize docs, in my case it is rails so i'll just the active support method, but good to know

Comment: Anyone know if class_name can include namespaces? E.g. "Module1::Module2::Klass"?